# Key value pairs array into array object

Tags: angular, typescript

```
pops = [
    [
      {
        key: 'test1',
        value: '0'
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        key: 'test2',
        value: '0'
      },
      {
        key: 'test3',
        value: '0'
      }
    ]
  ];
```

need to convert into this format

```
formated =
[{
 'test1':'0',
},
{
 'test2':'0',
 'test3':'0'
}]
```

I tried to solve the problem with this code but had no luck.
can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thank you.

```
let formated = []
let count=0
for(let item of this.pops){
 
  for(let prop of item){
   formated[count].push(prop.key:prop.value)
  }
  count++;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved with a combination of `map` and `reduce`:

```js
const pops = [
    [
      {
        key: 'test1',
        value: '0'
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        key: 'test2',
        value: '0'
      },
      {
        key: 'test3',
        value: '0'
      }
    ]
  ];
  
const formatted = pops.map(i =>  i.reduce( (acc,x) => ({...acc,[x.key]:x.value}),{}));

console.log(formatted);
```